# How to handle GoBack in the Navigation Drawer in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an App using this third party control: [DrawerLayout for Windows Phone 8.1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb386b/implementing-navigation-drawer-for-windows-phone-8-1/)

I'm having some problems because most of the examples are finishing the App after closing the Drawer however I have several Frames and I need to go back to the previous one no to the first one.

I think my main problem is because firstly I override the Back Button in the App.xaml.cs with this well-known code:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
    this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (frame == null)
        return;

    if (frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

However when I implement the Drawer I need to add something like this for handling the Hardware Back Button:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen)
    {
        DrawerLayout.CloseDrawer();//Close drawer on back press  
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame == null)
            return;

        if (frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried different ideas like Adding a public variable, deleting the else (it didn't work because of later it automatically closed the frame). Maybe anyone has any idea how to fix it because I'd like that the first close the drawer and later go back to the previous Frame and it always redirect me to the First one.

Thanks for your worthy time.

Comment: are you unregistering hardware backpress in your OnNaviatedFrom method?
 HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Could you give me an idea?

Comment: Are you using multiple frames in your project? Or mulitiple pages within one frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actullay `OnNavigateTo` Method is called when the frame is navigated to (opened) and `OnNavigatedFrom` method is called when frame is closed. You need to register Hardware backpress on `OnNavigateTo` and unregister it in `OnNavigateFrom`.

See the example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! However if anyone use this control too it's important to say that this change must be done everywhere.